# Tackling deprecation of viewWillAppear in later versions of iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, deprecated, viewwillappear

soon I found out that viewWillAppear has been deprecated since iOS 6. I am pretty upset because 
it was used in all the tutorials that I learned from. So what should I do now when I want to develop apps for later versions and when I want to call this method. Is there some kind of substitution for it?

Thanks

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` is not deprecated. Did you mean `viewWillUnload` and `viewDidUnload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is NOT depracated as you can see in Apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:). Maybe you are talking about `viewDidUnload`. Apple changed the view controllers lifecycle and is not needed anymore. If you want to relese memory during memory warning you can still use the method -`didReceiveMemoryWarning`